# Android [retrofit] - unparsable date

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit

I send GET request with Retrofit and I have issue as below:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-05-09"
```

My object model:

```
public class Device {
    private int id;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private String connectionName;
    private String deviceName;
    private Date startConnection;
    private Location actualLocation;
    private User owner;

//getters setters and constructor
}
```

GET:

```
public void getAllDevicesForCurrentUser(){
        compositeDisposable.add(restAPI.getDevices("Bearer " + TokenHolder.getInstance().getToken())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Device>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<Device> devices) throws Exception {
                        initializeDevices(devices);
                    }
                }));
    }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Need more code. How do you do the call?

Comment: I add more code in first post.

Comment: @Bartosz20188 the issue is where you trying to parse the date. Your date format is not correct so share that part of code

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set a date format in your retrofit initialization. Here's how you can do it

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
.create();

Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
.build();
```

Comment: Thanks! I have the same problem with time.`Unparseable date: "00:06:00"`

Comment: "00:06:00" - what kind of date is this?

Comment: It's time, not date. In database I have Date as 2018-05-09 and in the other column time - 00:06:00

Comment: You will have to either use a custom adapter to parse Time or simply pass time with date like this .setDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")

Comment: Can I exclude parsing date and time from JSON?

Comment: yes you can use transient modifier for fields that you dont want to be deserialized

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fix this issue.

I add `@Expose` above all variable in objects and `Expose(deserialized = false)` in variable which i don't need parse from JSON.

Finally,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Answer (score -1):

Nowe I get

```
 io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "00:06:00"
```

I want to parse time to my  object Location actualLocation where

```
public class Device {
    private int id;
    private int phoneNumber;
    private String connectionName;
    private String deviceName;
    private Date startConnection;
    private Location actualLocation;
    private User owner;

//getters setters and constructor
}
```

and Location :

```
public class Location {
    private int id;
    private float gpsLatitude;
    private float gpsLongitude;
    private Date date;
    private Time time;
    private Device device;
}
```

Comment: That's not an answer, but an addition to your question, which you should update to describe the new issue/behavior